# JavaCompiler from JDK 1.6: how to write class bytes directly to byte[] array?

Tags: java, compilation, in-memory, jsr199

So I recently learned of the new [JavaCompiler API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) available in JDK 1.6.  This makes it very simple to compile a `String` to a `.class` file directly from running code:

```
String className = "Foo";
String sourceCode = "...";

JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

List<JavaSourceFromString> unitsToCompile = new ArrayList<JavaSourceFromString>() 
    {{ 
         add(new JavaSourceFromString(className, sourceCode)); 
    }};

StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, unitsToCompile).call();
fileManager.close();    

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(className + ".class");
IOUtils.copyStream(fis, bos);

return bos.toByteArray();
```

You can grab the source to `JavaSourceFromString` from the [Javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

This will very handily compile `sourceCode` to `Foo.class` in the current working directory.

**My question is**: is it possible to compile straight to a `byte[]` array, and avoid the messiness of dealing with `File` I/O altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could create your own `javax.tools.JavaFileManager` implementing class where you would return your own implementation of `javax.tools.FileObject` which would then write it out to memory instead to disk. So for your subclass of `javax.tools.FileObject` `Writer openWriter() throws IOException` method you would return a `java.io.StringWriter`. All the methods should be converted to their `String` counterparts.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that there is no standard API to write bytecodes to a byte array is that compiling a single Java source file may result in multiple bytecode files.  For example, any source file with nested / inner / anonymous classes will result in multiple bytecode files.

If you roll your own JavaFileManager, you will need to deal with this situation.

Answer (score 2):

The demo application that shipped with the JSR 199 API had an in-memory compile-from-string example (which is indeed using a `MemoryFileManager`). Maybe have a look at it [here](http://trac.clermont.cemagref.fr/projets/SimExplorer-test/browser/SimExplorer/trunk/src/sun/tools/evalexpr/CompileFromString.java?rev=479) or [here](http://shinobun.org/svn/repos/trunk/demo/demo-mustang/src/main/java/org/shinobun/demo/mustang/tools/CompileFromString.java) (these samples are a bit outdated though, they will require slight changes). Also maybe check the [How to compile on the fly?](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/12/17/how-compile-fly) article on Java.net.

PS: I didn't look at all the details, but I'm don't think it handles the cases mentioned by [Stephen C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130039/javacompiler-from-jdk-1-6-how-to-write-class-bytes-directly-to-byte-array/2130244#2130244).