# how to create a dynamic class at runtime in Java

Tags: java, class, dynamic

Is it possible to create a new Java file from an existing Java file after changing some of its attributes at runtime?

Suppose I have a java file

```
public class Student {
    private int rollNo;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
    // constructor
}
```

Is it possible to create something like this, provided that `rollNo` is a key element for the table?

```
public class Student {
    private StudentKey key;
    private String name;
    //getters and setters
    //constructor
}

public class StudentKey {
    private int rollNo;
    // getters and setters
    // construcotors
}
```

Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: Hint:To answer ur Q? First of all think in this way like can a class be created at run time. because every class needs to be load, compile and then run.Can this possible at run time only?

Comment: @javauser: You can do this at runtime with the Java Compiler API (see [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130039/javacompiler-from-jdk-1-6-how-to-write-class-bytes-directly-to-byte-array/2130290#2130290)). This doesn't apply here (at least not alone) because the OP wants to modify an already compiled/loaded type. But to strictly answer your question, it is possible.

Comment: @javauser: please make only relevant comments.  No riddles, thanks.  In addition to that, "eleet speak", like your *"To answer ur Q?"* is frowned on SO.  Please refrain from doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/).